# Java generic wildcards: if something wants ? extends T, what's wrong with T?

Tags: java, generics

```
   protected List<? extends ErrorTO> errors = new ArrayList<ErrorTO>();

    public abstract Collection<? extends ErrorTO> getErrors();

    public void registerError(ErrorTO e) {
        errors.add(e);
    }
```

there is a compiling error of line "errors.add(e)", it is expecting some type of "? extends ErrorTO" and does not like ErrorTO? why and ho to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: don't you mean that you don't know how to use generics correctly? this is not a problem with the language.

Comment: An almost identical example (and an explanation) is given in the Java Tutorial page on wildcards: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html.

Comment: It's not possible to give a solution, because we don't know what you're trying to achieve.  Why do you want to use wildcards here?

Comment: @user1329572: Perhaps OP meant "not working as expected"? No need for offense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<? extends ErrorTO>` is *not* a List that can contain anything that extends `ErrorTO`.

It is a List of an (unspecified) subclass of `ErrorTO`.

if `MyErrorTO` extends `ErrorTO`, then I can create a `List<MyErrorTO>` and assign it to `errors`.

Your code will then try to add an `ErrorTO` to my List, which is illegal - my List can only contain a specific subclass of `ErrorTO`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know that `getErrors` will return a `Collection<ErrorTo>`; it might instead return a `Collection<SomeSubclassOfErrorTo>`. If you then tried to add an `ErrorTo` that wasn't of this subclass to the collection, type safety would be violated. For this reason, the compiler will not let you do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add anything to a `List<? extends ErrorTO>`. Make it a `List<ErrorTO>`.

`List<? extends ErrorTO>` means: a list of some unknow class, which is ErrorTO or extends ErrorTO. So obviously, if you could add something to it, its type-safety would be broken.

Comment: "You can't add anything" except `null`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help a little. Lets say we have classes

```
class Fruit {}
class Pear extends Fruit{ void methodA(){} }
class Apple extends Fruit{ void methodB(){} }
```

and we want to create method like this

```
public static void method(List<? extends Fruit> list, Fruit f) {
    list.add(f); //<-- why is this forbidden?
}
```

As `list` argument this method can accept lists like

```
ArrayList<Fruit>
ArrayList<Apple>
ArrayList<Pear>
```

If the argument would be `new ArrayList<Pear>();` then compiler shouldn't allow to add elements like Fruit or Apple.

But compiler can't know what kind of list he will be dealing with. Because of that lack of knowledge it is impossible to add any elements via `List<? extends Fruit> list` reference.

Comment: "it is impossible to add any elements" except `null`

Comment: @newacct You are right but I didn't want to mention it to make example easier to understand :)